# join symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to produce

> 1 • 2

But below code won't work?

```
const arr = [1,2]

console.log(arr.join(' - '))

console.log(arr.join(' &#8226; ')) // doesn't work
```

Comment: Why do you use `-` instead of `•` in your code?

Comment: That's an HTML character entity, which is pretty useless in JS. You needed to use `\u2022` as an escape sequence in JS string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it directly?

```js
const arr = [1, 2],
      res = arr.join(' • ');
      
      console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using HexCode...

```js
const arr = [1,2]

console.log(arr.join(' - '))

console.log(arr.join( '\u2022' )) // doesn't work &#8226;
```